# Convert this date format

Tags: java, android

How to parse this following date format in java ?
I really dont understand the format.Can you please tell me which class to use for parsing date format?

2014-01-12T11:52:06-06:00

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the SimpleDateFormat with the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" .. More details can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Note : Time Zone with colon (without timezone abbreviation)  is only supported in Java 7

Answer (score 1):

you have two options: you could try  DateFormat.getDateInstance() -see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html for constructor options.

DateFormat has  built-in a bunch of date and time formatting options, but if it does not  fulfills your requirements, check [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for custom formatting.

edit: just now saw the android tags. changed to android links

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private DateFormat date=new DateFormat();   
private TextView dateTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dateTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    dateTextView.setText(date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss-06:00", new Date()));

}
```

}

I just don't know what is this 06:00 but i did it that way.